# Adding custom meta tags to nodes, dependent on author name?

Tags: meta-tags

I would like to add the meta tag

```
`<meta name="robots" content="follow,noindex">`
```

to all nodes (content type is article) written by specific authors, not only for their new articles but for the few hundred that already exist.

I've installed metatag and metatags-quick, neither seem to offer the functionality I'm after. This is a drupal 7 installation.

I'd rather not have to edit the php, as I'm unfamiliar with that, but I will if I have to.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a metatag module which gives you that level of granularity; you might have to do it in code.

Fortunately, it's pretty easy. You'll need a [custom module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules), in which you should implement [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), and use [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) to add the meta tag based on custom logic.

Very brief example:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'foo' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    if ($node->name == 'admin') {
      $tag = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
          'name' => 'robots',
          'content' => 'follow,noindex',
        ),
      );
      drupal_add_html_head($tag, 'MYMODULE:robots:noindex');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm following the drupal tutorial on creating modules. Guess I'll have to learn PHP. I'll set this as the accepted answer once I've got it working.